# Reply message received but the receiving thread has already received a reply - error in spring integration

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

Here I have a spring integration flow and when multiple parallel calls are coming to this flow I'm getting error saying -

```
Reply message received but the receiving thread has already received a reply: ErrorMessage [payload=org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred in message handler [bean 'myFlow.aggregator#1'; defined in: 'class path resource 
[com/example/config/SpringIntegrationConfiguration.class]'; from source: 'bean method myFlow']; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: 'upperBound' must not be null., failedMessage=GenericMessage 
[payload=<200,[x-content-type-options:"nosniff", x-xss-protection:"1; mode=block", cache-control:"no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate", pragma:"no-cache", expires:"0", x-frame-options:"DENY", content-length:"0", date:"Wed, 05 Apr 2023 20:26:14 GMT", 
x-envoy-upstream-service-time:"28", server:"envoy"]>, headers={date=1680726374000, dataIndicator=false, content-length=0, server=envoy, sequenceDetails=[[88568fbe-093f-eb0c-5641-5ad0f8146727, 1, 1], [2a761702-6de6-7d1e-70be-8de17cb0dfb8, 1, 5], 
[47817b6b-6001-aeb0-ad33-3d381a78bea4, 1, 1]], gatherResultChannel=org.springframework.integration.channel.QueueChannel@47a1bb33,SystemCd=01, transfer-encoding=chunked, 
errorChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@18bd0ff1, vary=accept-encoding, originalErrorChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@18bd0ff1, sequenceSize=2, http_statusCode=200 OK, 
createdAt=2023-04-05 20:26:14.481, requestNumber=4915032, correlationId=efda3694-5da2-c51a-c3a5-b9d92999f42a, id=87fd4dd6-90a9-ef73-49da-c3be149a9792, cache-control=no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate, contentType=application/json, timestamp=1680726374805, 
sequenceNumber=2,rQty=0, product-type=Personal, pragma=no-cache, endPoint=ENDPOINT1, replyChannel=org.springframework.integration.channel.FixedSubscriberChannel@9fb399f, dbID=867542, 
user-id=TestAutomation, dataFlag=true}], headers={id=98d42441-a4a4-45a1-0686-5581459dbed9, timestamp=1680726374805}]
```

here's the whole stacktrace -

```
    pool-19-thread-1 ERROR com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: (was java.util.ConcurrentModificationException) (through reference chain: org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.AbstractJacksonLayout$LogEventWithAdditionalFields["logEvent"]->org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jLogEvent["message"]) com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: (was java.util.ConcurrentModificationException) (through reference chain: org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.AbstractJacksonLayout$LogEventWithAdditionalFields["logEvent"]->org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jLogEvent["message"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:397)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:356)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.StdSerializer.wrapAndThrow(StdSerializer.java:316)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFieldsFiltered(BeanSerializerBase.java:815)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.UnwrappingBeanSerializer.serialize(UnwrappingBeanSerializer.java:132)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.UnwrappingBeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(UnwrappingBeanPropertyWriter.java:127)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:755)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:178)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider._serialize(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:480)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:319)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter$Prefetch.serialize(ObjectWriter.java:1516)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter._writeValueAndClose(ObjectWriter.java:1217)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.writeValue(ObjectWriter.java:1059)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.AbstractJacksonLayout.toSerializable(AbstractJacksonLayout.java:344)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.JsonLayout.toSerializable(JsonLayout.java:292)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.AbstractJacksonLayout.toSerializable(AbstractJacksonLayout.java:292)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.JsonLayout.toSerializable(JsonLayout.java:70)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.AbstractJacksonLayout.toSerializable(AbstractJacksonLayout.java:52)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.AbstractStringLayout.toByteArray(AbstractStringLayout.java:282)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.AbstractLayout.encode(AbstractLayout.java:209)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.AbstractLayout.encode(AbstractLayout.java:37)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractOutputStreamAppender.directEncodeEvent(AbstractOutputStreamAppender.java:197)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractOutputStreamAppender.tryAppend(AbstractOutputStreamAppender.java:190)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractOutputStreamAppender.append(AbstractOutputStreamAppender.java:181)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.tryCallAppender(AppenderControl.java:161)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppender0(AppenderControl.java:134)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppenderPreventRecursion(AppenderControl.java:125)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppender(AppenderControl.java:89)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.callAppenders(LoggerConfig.java:542)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.processLogEvent(LoggerConfig.java:500)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.log(LoggerConfig.java:483)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.log(LoggerConfig.java:417)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AwaitCompletionReliabilityStrategy.log(AwaitCompletionReliabilityStrategy.java:82)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger.log(Logger.java:161)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.tryLogMessage(AbstractLogger.java:2205)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessageTrackRecursion(AbstractLogger.java:2159)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessageSafely(AbstractLogger.java:2142)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessage(AbstractLogger.java:1994)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logIfEnabled(AbstractLogger.java:1852)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogAdapter$Log4jLog.log(LogAdapter.java:270)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogAdapter$Log4jLog.info(LogAdapter.java:230)
    at org.springframework.core.log.LogAccessor.info(LogAccessor.java:292)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.LoggingHandler.handleMessageInternal(LoggingHandler.java:191)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:56)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.FixedSubscriberChannel.send(FixedSubscriberChannel.java:77)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.interceptor.WireTap.preSend(WireTap.java:166)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel$ChannelInterceptorList.preSend(AbstractMessageChannel.java:469)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:309)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:272)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:187)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:166)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:109)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:457)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.doProduceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:325)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:268)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:232)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:142)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:56)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:115)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:133)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:106)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:72)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:317)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:272)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:187)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:166)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:109)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:457)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.doProduceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:325)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:268)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:232)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:142)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:56)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:115)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:133)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.access$000(UnicastingDispatcher.java:55)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher$1.run(UnicastingDispatcher.java:114)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:57)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedHashIterator.nextNode(LinkedHashMap.java:719)
    at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedEntryIterator.next(LinkedHashMap.java:751)
    at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedEntryIterator.next(LinkedHashMap.java:749)
    at java.base/java.util.AbstractMap.toString(AbstractMap.java:551)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2951)
    at java.base/java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:172)
    at java.base/java.util.AbstractMap.toString(AbstractMap.java:556)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2951)
    at java.base/java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:172)
    at java.base/java.util.AbstractMap.toString(AbstractMap.java:556)
    at org.springframework.messaging.MessageHeaders.toString(MessageHeaders.java:348)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2951)
    at java.base/java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:172)
    at org.springframework.messaging.support.GenericMessage.toString(GenericMessage.java:120)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2951)
    at java.base/java.util.Objects.toString(Objects.java:160)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.LoggingHandler.createLogMessage(LoggingHandler.java:209)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.LoggingHandler.lambda$handleMessageInternal$0(LoggingHandler.java:179)
    at org.springframework.core.log.LogMessage$SupplierMessage.buildString(LogMessage.java:155)
    at org.springframework.core.log.LogMessage.toString(LogMessage.java:70)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2951)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.message.ObjectMessage.getFormattedMessage(ObjectMessage.java:55)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.jackson.MessageSerializer.serialize(MessageSerializer.java:44)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.jackson.MessageSerializer.serialize(MessageSerializer.java:33)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:728)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.serializeAsField(SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.java:208)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFieldsFiltered(BeanSerializerBase.java:807)
    ... 79 more"
```

payload=<200 - is the response of flow5().
I'm calling this myFlow from controller through gateway. I've total 4 APIs in my microservice and all the APIs are using this same configuration. When I'm running my automation suite on this service then this error is coming.
when I hit the APIs from the postman then it works fine but when lot of parallel calls are coming then this issue is occurring.

Here is my Spring integration config -

```
@Bean
  public IntegrationFlow myFlow() {
    return flow ->
        flow.handle(validatorService, "validateRequest")
            .channel(c -> c.executor(Executors.newCachedThreadPool()))
            .log("Parallel Processing started")
            .scatterGather(
                scatterer ->
                    scatterer
                        .applySequence(true)
                        .recipientFlow(savingRequestToTheDB())
                        .recipientFlow(flow1())
                        .recipientFlow(flow2())
                        .recipientFlow(conditionToCallFlow3, flow3())
                        .recipientFlow(
                            conditionToCallFlow4,
                            flow4()),
                gatherer -> gatherer.outputProcessor(gatherAndProcess()))
            .log("Parallel Processing ended")
            .gateway(getSomethng(), f -> f.errorChannel("cdErrorChannel"))
            .split()
            .channel(c -> c.executor(Executors.newCachedThreadPool()))
            .scatterGather(
                scatterer ->
                    scatterer
                        .applySequence(true)
                        .recipientFlow(prepareResponse())
                        .recipientFlow(conditionToCallFlow5, flow5()),
                gatherer ->
                    gatherer.outputProcessor(gatherLionResponse()))
.to(savingLionResponse());
  }
```

This is the savingLionResponse method -

```
private MessageGroupProcessor gatherLionResponse() {
    return lionsService::gatherLionResponse;
  }

 public Object gatherLionResponse(MessageGroup group) {
    String lionResponse;
    MessageHeaders headers;
    String JStage ;
    String JName ;
    long dbID;
    Optional<Message<?>> lionResponseMessage =
        group.getMessages().stream()
            .filter(m -> m.getHeaders().get("sequenceNumber", Integer.class) == 1)
            .findFirst();
    if (lionResponseMessage.isPresent()) {
      Message<?> message = lionResponseMessage.get();
      lionResponse= message.getPayload().toString();
      headers = message.getHeaders();
    } 
    logger.atInfo().log("Lion-Response-Body : " + lionResponse);

    return MessageBuilder.withPayload(lionResponse)
        .copyHeaders(headers)
        .removeHeaders(
            "Date",
            CommonConstants.D_FLAG,
            CommonConstants.CREATED_AT,
            CommonConstants.RE_QUANT);
  }
```

as per Artem replacing the second scatter-gather with publishSubscribeChannel -

@Bean

```
    public IntegrationFlow myFlow() {
return flow ->
        flow.handle(validatorService, "validateRequest")
                .channel(c -> c.executor(Executors.newCachedThreadPool()))
                .scatterGather(
                        scatterer ->
                                scatterer
                                        .applySequence(true)
                                        .recipientFlow(savingLoanRequestToTheDB())
                                        .recipientFlow(flow1())
                                        .recipientFlow(flow2())
                                        .recipientFlow(conditionToCallFlow3, flow3())
                                        .recipientFlow(
                                                conditionToCallFlow4,
                                                flow4()),
                        gatherer -> gatherer.outputProcessor(gatherAndProcess()))
                .gateway(getSomethng())
                .publishSubscribeChannel(
                        pubSub1 ->
                                pubSub1
                                        .subscribe(
                                                f ->
                                                        f.publishSubscribeChannel(
                                                                Executors.newCachedThreadPool(),
                                                                pubSub2 ->
                                                                        pubSub2
                                                                                .subscribe(flow5())
                                                                                .subscribe(prepareResponse())))
                                        .subscribe(f -> f.to(saveResponse())));
```

}

Comment: Please, share more about that `java.lang.IllegalStateException: 'upperBound' must not be null` exception. It looks like there is some race condition in the `SimpleMessageStore` used in the aggregator - gatherer in your case.

Comment: Hi @Artem I've pasted the error message in my post. Do u want me to post the gatherAndProcess(), savingLionResponse() code?

Comment: I've pasted the whole error message in the post

Comment: No. That's not what I've asked. I want to see the whole stack trace for that error. Yes, we see that problem is somewhere around your `gatherer.outputProcessor(savingLionResponse())`, but I doubt that your `savingLionResponse()` is guilty somehow. The error about `upperBound` indicated that there is some race condition in the `SimpleMessageStore` when it deal with the same group. Not clear how it can be the same group since it looks like you use standard sequencing. Or do you set a custom `id` into messages upfront which are not unique?

Comment: No @Artem, I'm not setting any custom id into the messages.

Comment: I've updated my post with the extended stacktrace.

Comment: Sorry, that JSON is not readable over here. Can't it be present as a normal Java stacktrace?

Comment: Actually I copied that stacktrace from gcp logging console. If u don't mind could u copy it from here and paste it in notepad and check pls.

Comment: Actually I'm not able to replicate the same scenario in my local so I'm not getting normal stackTrace, I had to copy it from my gcp log console.

Comment: Yeah... That is just call stack and doesn't show any error. I'm not sure how to analyze it. Would be great to be able to reproduce locally.

Comment: not able to reproduce it locally Artem. Not sure how do I solve this issue 

Comment: Try to remove that `.channel(c -> c.executor(Executors.newCachedThreadPool()))`. Kinda make it sequential. I'm still puzzled how that is possible if you really rely on a default random ids for messages. The `upperBound` for group can be null only in case if you `removeMessageGroup()`, but this remove happens only if we release the group and that is not clear how that is possible if you rely on a default release strategy. What does your `savingLionResponse()` does?

Comment: inside savingLionResponse() I loop through the groupMessages and then I save the response that it got from prepareResponse(). I return the prepareResponse() response from this method and that's what goes out from gateway to the controller as a response of this rest endpoint.  flow5() is called parallelly and it just returns 200OK if successful otherwise it errors out and the flow breaks

Comment: Any chances to see that code, please? The `gatherer` waits for replies from both of your `prepareResponse()` and `flow5()`., Although since I see that `conditionToCallFlow5`. So, you may have just only one item in the sequence to gather in the end.

Comment: Sure @Artem, I've modified my post with the savingLionResponse() method code. Kindly let me know if anything else is required from my end to debug the issue.

Comment: The simple project to be able to reproduce. The current solution you only can debug yourself and I'm not sure how to do that on GCP.

Comment: It is not a `MessageGroupProcessor` to do some extra work like your `saveResponse()`. Consider to move that DB interaction downstream after the scatter-gather. It also would be great to move that logic about throwing exception downstream as well. The aggregator must just do an aggregation even if it is not full. The business logic on the aggregated data must be done outside of an aggregator scope.

Comment: Sure Artem. Let me move the db interaction after scatter-gather inside .to()

Comment: Hi @ArtemBilan even that didn't resolve the issue.

Comment: Sorry, without a simple project to reproduce I cannot help. I believe there are many other variables in your project we are not aware yet. Also looking into your current `MessageGroupProcessor` it does not feel like you need a Scattter-Gather for that part of your logic at all. You may look into a plain `publishSubscribeChannel()` where you would wait for a reply only from one subscriber. You current gatherer logic takes care only about one specific message in a group. So, why care about group at all if you can simply rely on an answer from one service as is?

Comment: How do I handle the condition here for flow5() ? could you pls help me with an example code

Comment: See `filter()`. It sends a message downstream if `true` and can send a message to a `discardChannel` otherwise.

Comment: Hi @ArtemBilan, I've updated my post with the full stacktrace

Comment: Yeah... That `JsonMappingException` has nothing to do with an `upperBound` we had in the beginning. Looks like that `AbstractJacksonLayout` is not thread-safe. But this is fully different story....

Comment: Hi @ArtemBilan, I have implemented publishSubscribeChannel() -    .gateway(getSomethng(), f -> f.errorChannel("cdErrorChannel"))          .publishSubscribeChannel(
                pubSub -> pubSub.subscribe(prepareResponse()).subscribe(flow5()))
            .to(savingLionResponse());   but here the problem is myFlow is not waiting for .publishSubscribeChannel()to process and before itself it's returning the response from .gateway(getSomethng(), f -> f.errorChannel("cdErrorChannel")) back to the gateway and after that publishSubscribeChannel() starts processing. How to resolve this?

Comment: I want to stich .publishSubscribeChannel() to the .gateway() and once .publishSubscribeChannel() is completed then I want to go to the .to(). If there's any error in any of the flow in .publishSubscribeChannel() then I want to break the flow and want to  throw error.  Now this throwing error part is already done as part of the previous code.

Comment: You need one more top level `publishSubscribeChannel`. One of the subscribers would your gateway with that `publishSubscribeChannel` you already have and another one is just `to()`. So, something like this `publishSubscribeChannel(pubSub -> gateway(...)).to()`. This way you still will be able to rethrow an exception from a gateway and be able to continue processing on `to()` as a second subscriber.

Comment: Hi @ArtemBilan,I have modified the post with the code that u suggested (if I have understood u correctly).But still I'm getting two issues- 1. `getSomethng()` flow's response is being returned from this flow to the gateway even before processing the subsequent flows. 2. `gatherAndProcess()` flow's output is getting circulated to `getSomethng()`, `flow5()` and `prepareResponse()`, but I want `getSomethng()` to take `gatherAndProcess()`'s output as payload and  `prepareResponse()` & `flow5()` should get `getSomethng()`'s output and process parallelly and in the end `.to()` should execute.

Comment: The `getSomethng()` must be as a `transform(getSomethng())` as a top-level just after that your `scatterGather` with a `gatherAndProcess()`. The you indeed do `publishSubscribeChannel()` where second subscriber will be your `to(saveResponse())` and the same result of `getSomethng()` is going to be send to your sub-flow with an executor.

Comment: You mean getSomethng() should not go inside .publishSubscribeChannel(), instead it should be like   -  `.scatterGather(...).transform(getSomethng()).publishSubscribeChannel();`  ?

Comment: Just to let you know here `getSomethng()` is an IntegrationFlow

Comment: Then use `.gateway(getSomethng())`

Comment: Pls see my updated code. But still it's not waiting till the end (`.to()`) but it's returning the response of `.prepareResponse()` because that's taking less time to process, on the other hand `.flow5()` is doing a httpOutbound call so that's happening after gateway receives the response and in the end `to(saveResponse())`. I want to continue till `.to()` and then return the response of `saveResponse()`. I mean ultimately I want to return the response of `.prepareResponse()` as the response of the gateway but after saving the response and calling `.flow5()`.

Comment: OK. So it has to be something like `.gateway(getSomethng()). .gateway(subFlow -> pubSub.(flow5 and prepareResponse)).to(saveResponse())`. You send to `flow5` and `prepareResponse` a result from the `getSomethng`. Your `flow5` must be one-way and only `prepareResponse` must return reply. Then after this gateway it comes back to the main flow continues with a `prepareResponse` to the .to(saveResponse()).

Comment: But Artem if there's an error in flow5() then I don't want to  send any response but error and break the flow. And also if there's an error in saving the response in `saveResponse()` then also I don't want to send any response but error and break the flow. So I need to wait for `.flow5()` &`.saveResponse()`, when both of them gives green signal then I want to send the `. prepareResponse()` 's output.Hope I'm making sense to you. FYI 'flow5()' does an http call which is just to sync the downstream so it'll not send any response but 200OK if sync was successful.

Comment: Then you must not use an `Executors.newCachedThreadPool()` and let those two subscribers to be called sequentially.  And yes, one-way HTTP call must be first and only then a second subscriber for that `prepareResponse` for reply.

Comment: Then I think `.scatterGather()` only will be fit for my requirement. Because I'll have to run those two flows parallelly that's the requirement.

Comment: Yeah... So, need to send them in parallel and really wait for replies or errors from both of them. Then yes, a scatter-gather is the way. However it may perform it in parallel if input channels of those recipient sub-flows are an executor channel. Otherwise they are performed sequentially.